# How do I add percentage of chance for something to happen?

Tags: python

For example, I have

```
import random

TimeAdj = ("New", "Old")
adj = ("fancy", "elegant")
place = ("street", "market")

print random.choice(TimeAdj) + ' ' + random.choice(adj) + ' ' + random.choice(place)
```

But I want {adj} to have 60% of chance to happen (without adding spaces), how do I do that?

Comment: `+ random.choice(("",'  ' + random.choice(adj))) + `

Comment: I did something like this for a chatbot that I'm writing. Shame it's in C#.

Comment: @nbryans Slight modification: `...+ random.choice("", ' ' + random.choice(adj)) +...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common pattern you'll want to consider is to build up the string that you want to print before you have the print statement.

```
import random

TimeAdj = ("New", "Old")
adj = ("fancy", "elegant")
place = ("street", "market")

string = random.choice(TimeAdj) + ' ' 
if random.random() < 0.5:
    string += random.choice(adj)
    string += ' '
string += random.choice(place)

print string
```

Here the percentage is 50% but that could be modified to any percentage you want.

Also, instead of using the += on a string, you'll want to look at [Efficient String Concatenation in Python](https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/)

Answer (score 0):

This will choose (for the adjective position) either the empty string or a random choice from one of the adjectives

```
import random

TimeAdj = ("New", "Old")
adj = ("fancy", "elegant")
place = ("street", "market")

print random.choice(TimeAdj) + random.choice(('',' ' + random.choice(adj))) + ' ' + random.choice(place)
```

Comment: This is along the right lines but might result in uneven spacing between words.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I fixed it.

Comment: What do you see @Tagc ?

Comment: What if I wanted to make it have 70%?

Answer (score 0):

I needed similar functionality for a chatbot I'm developing in C#. She seems more human if her responses vary a bit. I addressed the problem by creating a [*builder*](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder) to allow a full response to be composed in stages.

I've tried tackling your problem by creating a stripped-down version of this. nbryan's solution will work if you just need the chance to be fixed at 50%, but this will help you out if you'd like to shake the probabilities up a little.

```
import random


class RandomStringBuilder(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._string_parts = []

    def with_raw(self, string):
        self._string_parts.append(string)
        return self

    def from_any(self, *phrases, chance=1.0, prefix=' '):
        if random.random() < chance:
            self._string_parts.append(prefix + random.choice(phrases))

        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        return ''.join(self._string_parts)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    builder = RandomStringBuilder()
    print(builder\
        .with_raw('Hey, this is an example of a')\
        .from_any('terrible', 'bad', 'good', 'great', chance=0.7)\
        .with_raw(' solution to your problem'))
```

**Example Runs**

```
Hey, this is an example of a great solution to your problem
Hey, this is an example of a solution to your problem
Hey, this is an example of a terrible solution to your problem
```